# Bifurcate file into chunks to transfer data to IoT device for software upgrade in android

Tags: java, android, file, iot

Facing an issue to convert the file into small chunks and transfer as bytes to IoT device in android for a software upgrade.

In detail, mobile app will download the software upgrade file from cloud server and send the file to IoT devices to upgrade. Here the file should be sent into chunks and each chunk shouldn`t exceed 1024 bytes.

Here is my sample code to convert file into small byte chunks,

```
byte[] bytes1024Size = new byte[1024];
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(upgradeFile);
byte content[] = new byte[1024];
int readCount = 0;
while((readCount = in.read(content)) > 0) {
  System.out.println(new String(content, 0, readCount-1));
  String resultString = "";
  String fileContentChunk = new String(content, 0, readCount-1);
  String cmd = "UC" + count + "1024" + 
                    Arrays.toString(fileContent.getBytes()) + "$";
  Log.d(TAG, "Sending command **** " + cmd);
  System.out.println("file chunk "+ fileContentChunk);
}

in.close();
//upgradeEndRequest();
System.out.println("File saved successfully!");
```

Any help will be appreciated.